# How to access path in function?

Tags: node.js, express

In app.js, I need to handle several similar routes like below.

```
app.get('/path1', function(req, res) {
    var path = some_processing_based_on_path('/path1');
    res.render(path);
}
```

I would like to "squeeze" them into one common route. This is what I think.

```
app.get('/path*', function(req, res) {
    var path = some_processing_on_path(???);
    res.render(path);
}
```

Basic requirements: able to access path in function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`req.path`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.path) to get the path of the request:

```
app.get('/path*', function(req, res) {
    var path = some_processing_on_path(req.path)
    res.render(path)
})
```

You can also use [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) to access named path parameters:

```
app.get('/path:id', function(req, res) {
    var path = some_processing_on_path(req.params.id)
    res.render(path)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a function to your controllers, then define the function later for all of the controllers to use.

here's an example:

```
module.exports = function (app, insecureApp) {

  router.post('/your/path/modification', upsert);
  router.put('/your/path/modification/2', upsert);
  function upsert(req, res, next) {
      model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.name}, req.body, {upsert: true}, function (err, docs){
          if (err) return next(err);
          res.json("document successfully updated");
      });
  }

  // apply this router to the following path
  app.use('/your/base/path/here', router);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add escape character before  special symbol i.e.
`app.get    ('/path\*',...)`

and you can access path with: `req.path`